# Can i get a value from other souce into my HTML code, and it will update?

Tags: javascript, php, html, api

I'm a beginner to HTML and CSS, and I'm building a very small website for sign ups to an self defense course. I would like to have the number of available spaces left to update which gets this specific number from another source (the sign up platform we're using - NemTilmeld)

Our website is on danish and so is NemTilmeld but here are the links, so you can see for your selves what I mean if you need it :-)
https://www.judoinfo.dk/kursus/selvforsvar-for-kvinder
https://www.nemtilmeld.dk/

Thanks in advance
Alexander

Comment: If the other site offers an API then it is probably straightforward.  You'll need to know an actual programming language though, not just html and css. You've tagged php and javascript so perhaps you know those.

Comment: where is the html being stored? what's the file extension?  If it's .php just render the data from the server